# Using phantomjs to crawl a sitemap

Tags: javascript, xml, xml-parsing, phantomjs

I am very new to phantomjs. I have been messing with the following for far too long. I know I am missing something very simple. I have the following sitemap.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">
  <url>
    <loc>/</loc>
    <changefreq>always</changefreq>
    <priority>1.0</priority>
  </url>
  <url>
    <loc>/vehicles</loc>
    <lastmod>2013-01-07</lastmod>
  </url>
</urlset>
```

Now all I am trying to do is use phantomjs to get the url values from the xml document. I have the following.

```
page.open("sitemap.xml", function(status) {
    if(status !== "success") {
        console.log("Unable to open sitemap.");
    } else {
        // Stuck here
        console.log(page.content);
    }
});
```

The contents of the xml file are printed to screen correctly, but how do I use the document now to play with the xml? I just need to be able to get the first child of each url node. I have tried parsing the xml document into a DOMParser, but that does not seem right. Your help will be much appreciated.

Also how do you debug phatomjs so I can see the object in its full glory? For example, If I console.log an object in Dev Tools, I can expand it and see the key - value pairs. I am guessing terminal does not offer this luxury?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [libxmljs](https://github.com/polotek/libxmljs) to parse your xml-string and get the data you want!

Comment: Well now thats awesome. Will give it a try. Whats the difference to using the DOMParser and the library suggested above?

Comment: libxmljs converts your xml into an javascript object which gives you all standard possibilities of working with javascript objects (looping and so on). you can read more here: http://blog.nodejitsu.com/6-must-have-nodejs-modules

Comment: Was under the impression the DOMParser does the same. Thanks very much anyway!

Comment: Can this be done when running phantomjs in Windows? Can't find any docs about how to require the libxmljs module, and how to install the module...

Comment: dont know about windows, i'm sorry

Answer (score 5):

PhantomJS allows you to call javascript from within the page context. Check out my solution using plain old javascript.

The assumption is the sitemap looks like so

```
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">
<url>
<loc>http://example.com/</loc>
<lastmod>2014-07-07T14:09:27+00:00</lastmod>
<changefreq>always</changefreq>
</url>
```

I can get the url in the above sitemap using the code below.

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('http://xxxx/static/sitemap/sitemap.xml', function() {
        var content = page.content;
        parser = new DOMParser();
        xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(content,'text/xml');
        var loc = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('loc');
        console.log(loc.length);
        for(var i=0; i < loc.length; i++)
        {
          var url=loc[i].textContent;

        }

        phantom.exit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another idea, you could inject jQuery into the page and just parse the xml as such:

```
page.open("sitemap.xml", function(status) {
    if(status !== "success") {
        console.log("Unable to open sitemap.");
    } else {
        // Stuck here
        console.log(page.content);
        page.injectJs('j-query.js');//path to jquery
        var output = page.evaluate(function(){
                            return $('url *:first-child');           
                       });
    }
});
```

Comment: I already tried to injectJs into the xml page, and it did not seem to work. Will give it another bash!

Answer (score 0):

Someone created a testsuite for testing XML Sitemaps using casperjs, maybe you can adopt the code for your specific needs.

From the author:

> This script will attempt to crawl through a specified sitemap to check children pages for broken urls, images, css, and Javascript. Errors will be recorded to the logfile specified.

Usage:

```
casperjs sitemap_xml_testing.js --sitemap=<URL TO SITEMAP> --logfile=<LOG FILE NAME>
```

[gmazin automated sitemap testing on Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/gmazin/sitemap.xml-automated-testing/overview)